# 'Make_Time_Features' object has no attribute 'list_of_features'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pycaret

I am attempting to run the Pycaret (2.2.3) module in order to compare regression models in my GCP cloud. My scikit-learn version is 0.23.2, as the newest versions are bizarrely unable to run Pycaret.

My code is as simple as:

```
df = df.loc[:, ['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'target']]

reg1 = setup(data = df, target = 'target',
             train_size = 0.7, fold_shuffle=True, imputation_type='iterative',
             normalize=True, ignore_low_variance = True, remove_outliers=True)

best = compare_models()
```

As I try to execute this code, the following error message shows up:

**AttributeError: 'Make_Time_Features' object has no attribute 'list_of_features'**

What to do?

Thanks in advance